# File upload not working correctly

Tags: php, file, upload, filenames

EDIT: HOW SHOULD I IMPLEMENT THE str_replace FUNCTION? IT ISNT WORKING. SEE THE CODE BELOW

I'm making a form in which people can upload images. The images are being resized so they fit in a image-carousel. I don't know how its possible, but when the image contains spaces or punctuation, the image will not be saved. When the image doesnt contains spaces it works fine. Can somebody please help me?

form part

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post"
 enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" style="margin:0 auto; width:70%; 
 color:black; font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
 font-size:16px; text-transform:none; font-weight:normal" >

<label for="afb1" style="color:black;">
afbeelding 1 (max 5Mb)
</label>
<input type="file" accept="image/*" name="afb1" id="afb1" style="float:right">
```

php part

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["afb1"]["name"]);
$extension1 = end($temp);
$newfilename1="afbeelding1.".$extension1;

if ((($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["fb1"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["afb1"]["size"] < 10000000)
&& in_array($extension1, $allowedExts)) {
if ($_FILES["afb1"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["afb1"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["afb1"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["afb1"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["afb1"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["afb1"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
if (file_exists('../upload/afbeeldingen/' . $newfilename1)) {
  echo $_FILES["afb1"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
    $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($_FILES["afb1"]["tmp_name"]);
    $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
    $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
    if ($photoY < $photoX*240/400) {
        $width=400; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
        $size=GetimageSize($_FILES["afb1"]["tmp_name"]);
        $height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
        $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
        ImageJPEG($images_fin,'../upload/afbeeldingen/'.$newfilename1);
        ImageDestroy($images_orig);
        ImageDestroy($images_fin);
    }
    else {
        $height=240; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
        $size=GetimageSize($_FILES["afb1"]["tmp_name"]);
        $width=round($height*$size[0]/$size[1]);
        $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor(400, 240);
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, (400-$width)/2, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
        ImageJPEG($images_fin,'../upload/afbeeldingen/'.$newfilename1);
        ImageDestroy($images_orig);
        ImageDestroy($images_fin);
    }
}
}
} else {echo "Invalid file";}
```

VERSION 2:

like this? it isnt working

```
$nameafb1=$_FILES["afb1"]["name"];
$search = array(" ","_","(",")","!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","-","+","=",";",":",">","'","/","<","?");
$nameafb1new = str_replace($search,"",$nameafb1);
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $nameafb1nieuw);
$extension1 = end($temp);
$newfilename1="afbeelding1.".$extension1;

if ((($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["fb1"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["afb1"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["afb1"]["size"] < 10000000)
&& in_array($extension1, $allowedExts)) {
if ($_FILES["afb1"]["error"] > 0) {
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["afb1"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
echo "Upload: " . $nameafb1new . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["afb1"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["afb1"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["afb1"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
if (file_exists('../upload/afbeeldingen/' . $newfilename1)) {
  echo $_FILES["afb1"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
} else {
    $images_orig = ImageCreateFromJPEG($_FILES["afb1"]["tmp_name"]);
    $photoX = ImagesX($images_orig);
    $photoY = ImagesY($images_orig);
    if ($photoY < $photoX*240/400) {
        $width=400; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
        $size=GetimageSize($_FILES["afb1"]["tmp_name"]);
        $height=round($width*$size[1]/$size[0]);
        $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
            ImageJPEG($images_fin,'../upload/afbeeldingen/'.$newfilename1);
        ImageDestroy($images_orig);
        ImageDestroy($images_fin);
    }
    else {
        $height=240; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
        $size=GetimageSize($_FILES["afb1"]["tmp_name"]);
        $width=round($height*$size[0]/$size[1]);
        $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor(400, 240);
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, (400-$width)/2, 0, 0, 0, $width+1, $height+1, $photoX, $photoY);
        ImageJPEG($images_fin,'../upload/afbeeldingen/'.$newfilename1);
        ImageDestroy($images_orig);
        ImageDestroy($images_fin);
    }
}
}    } else {echo "Invalid file";}
```

Comment: Try using the `trim()` function to the filename or `str_replace()`

Comment: could you please show me how?

Comment: Try `$nameafb1=trim($_FILES["afb1"]["name"]);`

Comment: You're welcome. I have posted an answer for you below. Simply tick the white checkmark next to it till it turns green, to properly close the question, if you are not aware of how the StackOverflow system works.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this.

You can use PHP's [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function.

```
$nameafb1=trim($_FILES["afb1"]["name"]);
```

This will "trim" unwanted spaces from the beginning and/or end.

or PHP's [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function which has the ability to replace all spaces found:

```
$string = " hello world ";
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
 echo $string;
```

so in your case that would be:

```
$nameafb1=$_FILES["afb1"]["name"];

$nameafb1 = str_replace(' ', '', $nameafb1);
```

You can also replace spaces using underscores:

```
$nameafb1=$_FILES["afb1"]["name"];

$nameafb1 = str_replace(' ', '_', $nameafb1);
```

---

Another option is using the [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) function:

```
$nameafb1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $nameafb1);
```

which will replace the spaces to underscores. You can delete the underscore in `'_'` and change it to `''` if you don't want them.

Comment: Thanks Jay. It's not showing `+` @JayBlanchard but much appreciated :) I guess you've attained your upvote max for the day(?)